# How many non negative integers have the sum less than 10 where the order does not matter?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I know how to solve for the case where for a + b + c <10, where a = 1, b = 0, c =0 is considered different to a = 0 , b =1 , c=0

That problem can be reduced to $a +b +c+d =10$,where d is the remainder,  which is a combinatorics problem, and leads to a solution of $\begin{pmatrix} 12 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

This is derived from splitting 10 into indistinguishable 1s, and calculating how many ways 4-1 partitions can be inserted.

How would I go about calculating where swapping a,b,c is not considered a different way?

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ in the related problem non-negative ? In this case, the problem is equivalent to determining the triples with sum not exceeding $10$

Comment: Your example "0+0+3 and 3+0+0 are the same" is confusing because $\{0,0,3\}$ is a set that only has $2$ elements.

Comment: (Again, after your edit) is set $\{1,0,0\}$ admissible then?

Comment: @drhab, yes sorry, I do not mean sets, thank you for pointing that out, is it clear now what I am attempting to ask?

Comment: So actually you are looking for the number of tuples $(a,b,c)$ where $a,b,c$ are nonnegative integers that satisfy $a+b+c<10$ and $a\leq b\leq c$. Is that a correct interpretation of your question?

Comment: @drhab, a tuple where a different order, does not result in a different tuple. I am not sure if there is a term for that?, so $(1,0,0) \neq (1,0), but (1,0,0) = (0,0,1)$

Comment: a tuple where a different order does not result in in a different tuple can only be of the form $(a,a,a,\dots,a)$. If you want $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ to be equivalent then you can accomplish that by only accepting $(0,0,1)$ where $a\leq b\leq c$ as I suggested. Then   $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$ are left out so there is no multiple counting.

Comment: Ok thanks, that is what I am after.

Comment: By brute force I find $53$ possibilities.

Comment: @drhab Yes me too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to drhab's comment: $a\le b\le c, a+b+c<10$: 
$$\sum_{a=0}^3 \sum_{b=a}^{\lfloor \frac{9-a}{2} \rfloor}\sum_{c=b}^{9-a-b} 1=\sum_{a=0}^1 \sum_{b=a}^{4}\sum_{c=b}^{9-a-b}1+ \sum_{a=2}^3\sum_{b=a}^{3} \sum_{c=b}^{9-a-b} 1=\\
\sum_{a=0}^1 \sum_{b=a}^{4}(10-a-2b)+\sum_{a=2}^3\sum_{b=a}^{3} (10-a-2b)=\\
\sum_{a=0}^1 ((10-a)(5-a)-2\cdot \frac{a+4}{2}\cdot (5-a))+\sum_{a=2}^3 ((10-a)(4-a)-2\cdot \frac{a+3}{2}\cdot (4-a))=\\
[(10\cdot 5-5\cdot 4)+(9\cdot 4-5\cdot 4)]+[(8\cdot 2-5\cdot 2)+(7\cdot 1-6\cdot 1)]=53.$$

Bruteforcing:
$$\begin{align}&(000), (001),(002),(003),(004),(005),(006),(007),(008),(009) \Rightarrow 10 \\
&(011), (012),(013),(014),(015),(016),(017),(018) \Rightarrow 8\\
&(022), (023),(024),(025),(026),(027) \Rightarrow 6\\
&(033), (034),(035), (036) \Rightarrow 4\\
&(044), (045) \Rightarrow 2\\
&(111), (112),(113),(114),(115),(116),(117) \Rightarrow 7\\
&(122), (123),(124),(125),(126) \Rightarrow 5\\
&(133), (134), (135) \Rightarrow 3\\
&(144) \Rightarrow 1\\
&(222), (223),(224),(225) \Rightarrow 4\\
&(233), (234) \Rightarrow 2\\
&(333) \Rightarrow 1.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 Yes. The partition function $P(n)$ cannot be used because the number of terms is fixed here: $3$

Answer (score 1):

For positive integers $n$, and nonnegative integers $s$, let $f(n,s)$ be the number of nonnegative integer $n$-tuples $(x_1,...,x_n)$ with $x_1 \le \cdots \le x_n$ such that $x_1 + \cdots + x_n \le s$.

Then we have the recursion
$$
f(n,s)=
\begin{cases}
1&\;\;\;\text{if}\;s=0\\[4pt]
s+1&\;\;\;\text{if}\;s > 0\;\text{and}\;n=1\\[4pt]
{\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor{s/n}\right\rfloor}}} f(n-1,s-nk)&\;\;\;\text{if}\;s > 0\;\text{and}\;n > 1\\
\end{cases}
$$
Explanation:

  For each possible value $k$ of $x_1$, the non-strictly ascending nonnegative integer $n$-tuple $(x_1,...,x_n)$, with $x_1=k$, and sum at most $s$, corresponds to a non-strictly ascending nonnegative integer $(n-1)$-tuple $(x_2-k,\cdots x_n-k)$, whose sum is at most $s-nk$.

Implementing the recursion in Maple, we get $f(3,9)=53$.

It follows that there are exactly $53$ nonnegative integer triples, up to a permutation of the components, whose sum is less than $10$.

Here's the Maple implementation . . .

[image]